# How to import a file having a function calling a function defined in the file importing the function?

Tags: python, function, import, module

I have two python files a.py and b.py.
a.py has a function `f()` defined.
a.py is supposed to import another function `g()` defined in b.py
The function `g()` is supposed to call function `f()` in a.py
How can this be implemented?

I tried but i got function `g()` not defined. It seems `g()` cannot be seen by a.py file

Comment: Could you sketch out this code?  It is a bit hard to follow your description.

Comment: you need to 
"from b import g"
and now you can call g in a.py

Answer (score 0):

In these cases your program fall in infinite circular import unless you import them locally in example:

a.py:

```
def f():
    from b import g
    print("f")
    g()

def ff():
    from b import gg
    print("ff")
    gg()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f()
```

b.py:

```
def g():
    from a import ff
    print("g")
    ff()

def gg():
    print("gg")
```

Now if you run a.py you will get this response:

```
f
g
ff
gg
```

I hope this helps you. If not tell me your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of circular import. You should not develop that kind of conditions in most cases but there might be possible solutions

**a.py**

```
def f():
    print("it's f() in a.py")
    import b  # Import 'b' within the function to avoid circular import
    b.g()
f()
```

**# b.py**

```
def g():
    print("it's g() in b.py")
    import a  # Import 'a' within the function to avoid circular import
    a.f()
g()
```

If still it doesn't works, because it might cause recursion error, Than try this,
**a.py**

```
def f():
    # Base case: If some condition is met, stop the recursion
    if some_condition:
        return
    # Other code in function
    b.g()
```

**b.py**

```
def g():
    # Base case: If some condition is met, stop the recursion
    if some_condition:
        return
    # Other code in function
    a.f()
```